# HttpsGetEnabled=false troubles with SOAPUI to import a WSDL; says client certificate required

Tags: wcf, https, soapui, wcf-binding

I have a service whihc deployed in dev server with httpsgetenabled = true and creatting a SOAP UI project works great as under preferrences -> SSL Settings -> i have added my client certificate that issued by same CA that had setup in IIS under https bindings. so far so good; but my organization had asked me to turnoff the HTTPSGETENABLED = FALSE; when I do that i cant create the SOAP UI project anymore though i have same settings as before it failed with some wiered error; when I tried to access it via IE it says that i dont have client certificate.
any idea how to get over this SSL error with SOAP UI and httpsgetenable = false?

note: i do have MEX endpoint exposed along with true endpoint.

Comment: It looks like httpsget should be enabled while adding the project in SAOPUI so that proxy can be genereated; there after it doest really care whether get is enabled or not; hope it helps if some one reach this...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like httpsget should be enabled while adding the project in SAOPUI so that proxy can be genereated; there after it doest really care whether get is enabled or not; hope it helps if some one reach this...